# Simple form association has conflict with default input class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple form. Everything worked fairly okey until I came to the point I wanted to add an association form. The association itself works fine so I'll skip that. Saving data works. The issue lays in the control of the input class in exceptions.

```html
<%= simple_form_for @fabmoment do |f| %>
       
  <%= f.input_field :title %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.error :title %>
  <%= f.input_field :description, rows: 7 %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.error :description %><br><br>
  <%= f.association :machines, as: :check_boxes, 
                               :label_method => lambda { |m| " #{m.name}" } %>
    
<% end %>
```

As you see I am very specific in where I put what, and this is because of my CSS library (W3.CSS). The problem is that in my initializer I put the class of `"w3-input"` as the default for inputs. But this doesn't work for my association checkboxes. At the moment I see that the label and input checkbox are not inline.

This wouldn't be the case if the `"w3-input"` class wouldn't be there. But I can't remove it, I can only go as deep as the `item_wrapper_tag` and the `item_wrapper_class`.

This his highly annoying. I have been busy with this for hours yesterday.

Why can't I do something like this:

```html
<%= f.association :machines, as: :check_boxes do |m| %>

  <%= m.check_box :machine_id, class: 'w3-check' %>
  <%= m.label :name, class: 'w3-validate' %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is an option to pass html attributes to simple_form tag by `input_html` and `label_html`.
You can find all options from [Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)
For your above issue you can do something like

```
<%= f.association :machines, as: :check_boxes, input_html:{class: 'w3-check'} ,label_html: {class: 'w3-validate'}%>
```

This will add `w3-check` class on all of the machines checkboxes and `w3-validate` on all of the Labels of those checkboxes and then you can style accordingly

Comment: With input_html I am finally able to reach the input tag of the item. Thanks, this solves 80% of my problem. I still am not able to reach the label tag though. This label_html targets the label above the list of checkboxes. Which is nice, but I need the label of one item to indeed add `w3-validate` on.

Comment: you can use `wrapper_html: {class: 'checkbox_container'}` this will add this class on the parent of all the checkboxes. You can then apply `css` by `.checkbox_container label{border:1px solid gray}` . this will apply this css on all of the labels which corresponds to `machines`

Comment: Thanks. I find it a little cumbersome, but if there is no other way of doing this than I suppose it will have to do. btw with sass isn't there a way to extend with a predefined class a css selector? Anyway I can look into this myself.

Comment: yes you can use `@extend` . Find the details from https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/